# Why is “of” in “the speed of 200 km/h”?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, word-meaning, expressions, style

I encounter expressions which are a name of a quantity + “of” + a value. Examples: “The car is going at the speed of 200 km/h.”, “The top of Mt. Everest is at the altitude of 8848 meters above sea.”, also “Alternatively cost index can be given in metric or "Airbus" units of kg/min.” ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cruise_(aeronautics)#Airliner_cruise))

Why are they so? With “the speed of 200 km/h” as the example, it seems that 200 km/h has a speed, and the expression is referring to that, like that “king of France” means that France has a king, and it's referring to him. That doesn't make sense with values because they don't have physical properties. Similarly in the example from Wikipedia, there is no unit of a unit.

My idea is that 200 km/h is a speed, so omitting the “of” is correct: “the speed 200 km/h” – 200 km/h is the speed, and the expression refers to it. If the quantity name and the value have to be separated by something, it could be “as: “The car is going with 200 km/h as its speed.”, which means that the role of 200 km/h relative to the car is its speed. That is similar to how I wrote above “with … as the example”, but often ugly.

Anyway, how should I understand such expressions with “of”? They go against my idea of what “of” means (a way to refer to properties).

Comment: When you say, "my idea of what 'of' means" I think you are saying "my idea of what 'of' translates to in my native language"  And in your native language you don't  use that word in this context.  -  But in English this is the idiom.  There is no logic or reason for it.  Part of what "of" means is the word used in expressions like "a speed of 100km/h".  Its just a weird fact about English. — I'm sure there are some weird things about every language

Comment: We use 'of' before units: a speed of 200 km/h. a weight of 20 tonnes, a delay of five hours. Here we are, indeed, discussing properties of a speed, a weight and a delay.

Comment: Similarly in English "of" is used to express material or composition eg "a sword of iron", "a shirt of fine silk" while other languages might use their equivalent of "in" or something else.